# Comment in HTML brakes the page displaying in Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have local web page. To automatically allow blocked content I added the MOTW:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

It works fine (Internet explorer doesn't show this annoying warning), but MS Edge on Windows 10 doesn't show styles, images a.o content.
When I deleted this line, the page loaded good.

I tried to check version of browser in JavaScript, and add commend to HTML in `$(document).ready` but the "allow blocked content" warning appears before `$(document).ready` executes.

I tried to use conditional comments in HTML like `<!--if IE>` but something went wrong in IE11.

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using, and how are you loading this file?

Comment: MS Edge 20.10240.16384.0

Comment: Which exactly file?

Comment: How are you opening your local web page?